# How to test Observable.timer

Tags: angular, unit-testing, timer, jasmine

I'm trying to test this piece of code:

```
discardChanges() {
    const timer = Observable.timer(1000);
    this.showSpinner = true;
    timer.subscribe(() => {
        this.showSpinner = false;
        this.toastr.success('Changes discarded');
        this.loadCondition(this.condition);
        this.studyConditionsForm.markAsPristine();
    });
}`
```

doing it with Jasmine like:

```
xit('should discard changes and navigate to conditions', fakeAsync(() => {
    expect(component.showSpinner).toBeFalsy();
    enter code herecomponent.discardChanges();
    expect(component.showSpinner).toBeTruthy();
    tick(1000);
    fixture.detectChanges();
    expect(component.showSpinner).toBeFalsy();
    discardPeriodicTasks();
  })
);`
```

but when running `ng test` I got this error:

`Error: 1 timer(s) still in the queue.​​`

I have read many post and I don't make it work, actually I had the same issue with another test doing it this way but magically worked before many tries (I don't like magic to be honest).

I hope someone can guide me, actually if there is another best way rather than using `const timer = Observable.timer(1000)` and make it testable would be great!

Thanks.

Comment: Try use `Observable.timer(1000).take(1)`

Comment: I never used Jasmine for testing, but when using an Observable timer, make sure you unsubscribe the timer. `this.subscription = timer.subscribe(...);subscription.unsubscribe();`

Comment: the take() unsubscribe after take arg times

Comment: I have updated my code to `discardChanges() {
    const timer = Observable.timer(1000).take(1);
    this.showSpinner = true;
    timer.subscribe(() => {
      this.showSpinner = false;
      this.toastr.success('Changes discarded');
      this.loadCondition(this.condition);
      this.studyConditionsForm.markAsPristine();
    });
  }` according to the comments and the same error persist, I also tried subscription.unsubscribe(); but it freeze.

Answer (score 2):

I'm using rxjs 6.x，copy your code and run `ng test` command, and test passes.
You can try to update rxjs to newer version and test again(attention: no `Observable.timer` in rxjs 6.x)
Here are codes:

```
import { timer } from 'rxjs';
 discardChanges() { // method of component class
    const source = timer(1000);
    this.showSpinner = true;
    source.subscribe(() => {
        console.log(1)
        this.showSpinner = false;
    });
  }
```

test specification code:

```
 it('should test discardChanges', fakeAsync(() => {
        expect(component.showSpinner).toBeFalsy();
        component.discardChanges()
        expect(component.showSpinner).toBeTruthy();
        tick(1000);
        expect(component.showSpinner).toBeFalsy();
        discardPeriodicTasks()
      }));
```